# Cant switch windows in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Every time I click on the buttons I get a error. Could anyone help me by providing a fix or telling me what the issue was because I cant see the issue.

Whenever the button is clicked it is supposed to open a new page and the side bar on the left with the buttons in should stay where they are at.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")  
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue") 


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # configure window
        self.title("Opium")
        self.geometry(f"{1100}x{580}")

        # configure grid layout (4x4)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

        # create sidebar frame with widgets
        self.content_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=30, weight="bold"))
        self.content_label.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=4, sticky="nsew", padx=(10, 0), pady=(20, 10))
        self.sidebar_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=140, corner_radius=0)
        self.sidebar_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4, sticky="nsew")
        self.sidebar_frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="Opium", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=30, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
        self.sidebar_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, text="Button 1", command=self.sidebar_button_event)
        self.sidebar_button_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.sidebar_button_2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, text="Button 2", command=self.sidebar_button_event)
        self.sidebar_button_2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.sidebar_button_3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, text="Button 3", command=self.sidebar_button_event)
        self.sidebar_button_3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.appearance_mode_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="Appearance Mode:", anchor="w")
        self.appearance_mode_label.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(self.sidebar_frame, values=["Light", "Dark", "System"],
                                                                       command=self.change_appearance_mode_event)
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))


    def open_input_dialog_event(self):
        dialog = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text="Type in a number:", title="CTkInputDialog")
        print("CTkInputDialog:", dialog.get_input())

    def change_appearance_mode_event(self, new_appearance_mode: str):
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode(new_appearance_mode)

    def change_scaling_event(self, new_scaling: str):
        new_scaling_float = int(new_scaling.replace("%", "")) / 100
        customtkinter.set_widget_scaling(new_scaling_float)

    def sidebar_button_event(self):
        try:
            self.right_frame.destroy()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        self.right_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, bg="white", width=900, height=580)
        self.right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=3, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.home_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.right_frame, text="Home", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=30, weight="bold"), bg="white")
        self.home_label.pack(side="top", fill="both", padx=20, pady=20)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you getting a specific error message, or are things just not working as intended?

Comment: _"Every time I click on the buttons I get a error."_ - please include the error in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the code and the error you are getting when clicking the buttons is

```
ValueError: ['bg'] are not supported arguments. Look at the documentation for supported arguments.
```

As the error already says, `bg` is not a supported argument by customtkinter.
https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkLabel#arguments

In your specific case you have to change the two instances of `bg="white"` to `bg_color="white"`.

```py
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # configure window
        self.title("Opium")
        self.geometry(f"{1100}x{580}")

        # configure grid layout (4x4)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

        # create sidebar frame with widgets
        self.content_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(
            self, text="", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=30, weight="bold"))
        self.content_label.grid(
            row=0, column=1, rowspan=4, sticky="nsew", padx=(10, 0), pady=(20, 10))
        self.sidebar_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(
            self, width=140, corner_radius=0)
        self.sidebar_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4, sticky="nsew")
        self.sidebar_frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(
            self.sidebar_frame, text="Opium", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=30, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
        self.sidebar_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(
            self.sidebar_frame, text="Button 1", command=self.sidebar_button_event)
        self.sidebar_button_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.sidebar_button_2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(
            self.sidebar_frame, text="Button 2", command=self.sidebar_button_event)
        self.sidebar_button_2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.sidebar_button_3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(
            self.sidebar_frame, text="Button 3", command=self.sidebar_button_event)
        self.sidebar_button_3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.appearance_mode_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(
            self.sidebar_frame, text="Appearance Mode:", anchor="w")
        self.appearance_mode_label.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(self.sidebar_frame, values=["Light", "Dark", "System"],
                                                                       command=self.change_appearance_mode_event)
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu.grid(
            row=6, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

    def open_input_dialog_event(self):
        dialog = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(
            text="Type in a number:", title="CTkInputDialog")
        print("CTkInputDialog:", dialog.get_input())

    def change_appearance_mode_event(self, new_appearance_mode: str):
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode(new_appearance_mode)

    def change_scaling_event(self, new_scaling: str):
        new_scaling_float = int(new_scaling.replace("%", "")) / 100
        customtkinter.set_widget_scaling(new_scaling_float)

    def sidebar_button_event(self):
        try:
            self.right_frame.destroy()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        self.right_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(
            self, bg_color="white", width=900, height=580)
        self.right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=3,
                              columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.home_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(
            self.right_frame, text="Home", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=30, weight="bold"), bg_color="white")
        self.home_label.pack(side="top", fill="both", padx=20, pady=20)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

For the next time please be so kind and include the error message you are getting with your question